# Insertion sort a nested list without using lambda

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

> [('Bath Spa University', '84%', '37%', '80%', '67%', '29%', '0%'),
> ('University of Chichester', '80%', '42%', '75%', '0%', '0%', '0%'),
> ('Canterbury Christ Church University', '76%', '40%', '70%', '0%', '0%', '49%'),
> ('Buckinghamshire New University', '78%', '39%', '82%', '0%', '0%', '52%'), ('Middlesex University', '82%', '48%', '80%', '57%', '75%', '54%')...

Above is an example of my list of lists. This is the code I have to insertion sort a list.

```
def insert_sort(lst):
   n = len(lst)
   for i in range(n):
      j = i
      while j > 0 and lst[j-1] > lst[j]:
         tmp = lst[j]
         lst[j] = lst[j-1]
         lst[j-1] = tmp
         j -= 1
```

I want to have the function sort the nested lists by the first element. Is there a way to do this without using lambda?

Comment: you are not using `lambda` in your code, so I don't get your question.

Comment: Do you mean that you wish your function could sort using an arbitrary definition of the key element, just like the built-in `sort()`, but without using a `lambda` for the `key=` parameter?

Comment: @Guillaume my code is just a standard insertion sort, the answers I have come across mostly use lambda in order to access the elements in the lists, I want to code a function that doesn't rely on lambda if that makes sense

Comment: @quamrana I guess that could work too yes

Comment: if you don't want a lambda, you can always define a named method, or use `operator.itemgetter(0)` :) also, the fun thing is that a simple `your_list.sort()` would sort the list like you want, since it would order each tuple by their 1st item (then 2nd item in case of equality of the 1st, etc.)

Comment: You can replace `lst[j-1] > lst[j]` by `lst[j-1][0] > lst[j][0]` if you only want to compare the first element of the tuples.

Comment: Note that it is pretty unclear what you are asking. You have shown us some code to sort a list. Can you tell us: 1) does your code run without crashing 2) what does the list look like after you have applied your function to it 3) how does that differ from what you would have wanted?

Comment: In other words, can you answer the question: what is it that doesn't satisfy you about your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand what you mean 'without lambda', if you don't want to use lambda in key parameter in sort, you can use **itemgetter**, Rember that don't try to implement your own sort on production, use the build-in sort method, which is fast.

```
data = [('Bath Spa University', '84%', '37%', '80%', '67%', '29%', '0%'),
        ('University of Chichester', '80%', '42%', '75%', '0%', '0%', '0%'),
        ('Canterbury Christ Church University', '76%', '40%', '70%', '0%', '0%', '49%'),
        ('Buckinghamshire New University', '78%', '39%', '82%', '0%', '0%', '52%'),
        ('Middlesex University', '82%', '48%', '80%', '57%', '75%', '54%')]

from operator import itemgetter

data.sort(key=itemgetter(0))

print(data)
```